# `inline`, `constexpr` or `noexcept` for declaration only functions

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

For functions that has no body, and are just used for type-checking purposes or in non-evaluated contexts, is there any adventage to mark such functions as `inline`, `noexcept` or `constexpr`? For example:

```
namespace _detail {
   template<class R, class T, class... Params>
   constexpr R result_type(R(T::*)(Params...)) noexcept;

   template<class R, class T, class... Params>
   constexpr R result_type(R(T::*)(Params...) const) noexcept;

   template<class R, class... Params>
   constexpr R result_type(R(*)(Params...)) noexcept;

   template<class R, class... Params>
   constexpr R result_type(R(&)(Params...)) noexcept;
}

template<class F>
struct result_type { typedef decltype(_detail::result_type(declval<F>())) type; }
```

Does these `constexpr` or `noexcept` mean something or have any effect at all in any sense?  I guess that it could even be misleading, because the user could understand these functions could have a definition somewhere else. Anyway, is there any naming convention to mark that these functions are meant to be used in non-evaluated contexts only, or whose purpose is just to calculate types?

Answer (score 1):

`noexcept` definitely makes a difference, since you could use the functions in unevaluated `noexcept` contexts.

`inline` is irrelevant. It only affects linkage of the implementation, and there is no implementation.

`constexpr` should, I think, make no difference, since there is no standard way of detecting whether an unevaluated expression is a constant expression. But there might be compiler-specific ways of doing it.

Comment: I have just checked that `declval` remains to be non-`constexpr` but it's `noexcept`, so I think you are right in all of your three answers.

Comment: `inline` or `constexpr` can be used to produce errors at compile time when these functions are used in evaluated context: https://godbolt.org/z/EohS1c

Comment: You mean, to forbid these functions are used in evaluated contexts, and generate the corresponding error before waiting at linking time?

Comment: I guess the relevant keyword here is `inline`. It's `constexpr` what makes no difference. The error also happens with `constexpr` but just because `constexpr` implies `inline`.